# Image load callback fired even if the image does not exists

Tags: jquery, html, image, error-handling, callback

I have the following code that is bugging me : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DU5/)

These are the desired behaviours:

- If the image does not exist, I want to load another image changing the `src` attribute
- If that image also fails loading, the image should be hidden.
- If the image successfully loads (exists), I want it to be shown

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <img id="myimage" src="nonono.jpg" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#test img").error(function () {
    console.log("error loading img " + $(this).attr("src"));
    $("#myimage").attr("src", "yuyuyu.jpg")
}).load(function () {
    console.log("success loading img " + $(this).attr("src"));
})

//--- Simulate a new image load
$("#myimage").attr("src", "yeyeye.jpg");
```

This is what the console output loosk like:

> GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/yeyeye.jpg 404 (Not Found)
>
> error loading img yeyeye.jpg (index):23
>
> success loading img yuyuyu.jpg (index):26
>
> GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/yuyuyu.jpg 404 (Not Found)

isn't it weird? both images does not exist, I'm expecting two times the error message, but I get a SUCCESS instead!

any idea? Am I missing something?

Thank you

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried to add a `setTimeout` to the `src` attribute change, to better understand which images does fire the `load` event.. and.. the load event is not fired!

see fiddle here: [**Fiddle with timeout**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DU5/3/)

**JS**

```
$("#test img").error(function(){
    console.log("error loading img " + $(this).attr("src"));
    setTimeout(function(){
             $("#myimage").attr("src", "yuyuyu.jpg")
    }, 1000)
}).load(function(){
    console.log("success loading img " + $(this).attr("src"));  
})
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is not weird, the function runs on *Complete* not *Success* so even an error is a completed request. See [jQuery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

If you load an image like this, you can access the status of the request.

```
$("#test img").load("yuyuyu.jpg", function(response, status, xhr) {
    alert(status); 
});
```

You can get the specific error code via: `xhr.status`
You can also get a textual representation of the error via: `xhr.statusText`

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DU5/1/). Also see another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DU5/2/).

Comment: I totally missed that, thank you. What if I want to handle both the errors (from the 1st and the replacement image)? any suggestions?

Comment: @BeNdErR since it's an onload event on the html element itself, you changing the `src` attribute doesn't change the fact that the load event will be fired a second time once the second image is loaded. It should work fine without amendments. You would have to detect if it is the second load, and then tell it to be removed though.